# No visible @interface for 'KeyboardPlugin' declares the selector 'getConfig' [IONIC, XCODE]

Tags: ionic, ios, xcode, macos

Estoy usando una maquina virtual con mac, para construir la app ios
**VMware 15
MAC Catalina 10.15
XCode 11.2.3
IONIC 6
Capacitor**

Soy nuevo en la construccion de archivo .ipa (ios) y cuando ejecuto la accion para construir el archivo .ipa para hacer las pruebas en otros dispositivos sin conectarlos al pc, aparecen los siguientes errores en Xcode

[image: error Xcode]

y en el archivo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

archivo completo

```
   /*
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 distributed with this work for additional information
 regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 specific language governing permissions and limitations
 under the License.
 */

#import "Keyboard.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <Capacitor/Capacitor.h>
#import <Capacitor/Capacitor-Swift.h>
#import <Capacitor/CAPBridgedPlugin.h>
#import <Capacitor/CAPBridgedJSTypes.h>

typedef enum : NSUInteger {
  ResizeNone,
  ResizeNative,
  ResizeBody,
  ResizeIonic,
} ResizePolicy;


@interface KeyboardPlugin () <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (readwrite, assign, nonatomic) BOOL disableScroll;
@property (readwrite, assign, nonatomic) BOOL hideFormAccessoryBar;
@property (readwrite, assign, nonatomic) BOOL keyboardIsVisible;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) ResizePolicy keyboardResizes;
@property (readwrite, assign, nonatomic) NSString* keyboardStyle;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int paddingBottom;

@end

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wprotocol"
// suppressing warnings of the type: "Class 'KeyboardPlugin' does not conform to protocol 'CAPBridgedPlugin'"
// protocol conformance for this class is implemented by a macro and clang isn't detecting that
@implementation KeyboardPlugin

NSTimer *hideTimer;
NSString* UIClassString;
NSString* WKClassString;
NSString* UITraitsClassString;

- (void)load
{
  self.disableScroll = !self.bridge.config.scrollingEnabled;

  UIClassString = [@[@"UI", @"Web", @"Browser", @"View"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
  WKClassString = [@[@"WK", @"Content", @"View"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
  UITraitsClassString = [@[@"UI", @"Text", @"Input", @"Traits"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    PluginConfig * config = [self getConfig];
  NSString * style = [config getString:@"style": nil];
  [self changeKeyboardStyle:style.uppercaseString];

  self.keyboardResizes = ResizeNative;
  NSString * resizeMode = [config getString:@"resize": nil];

  if ([resizeMode isEqualToString:@"none"]) {
    self.keyboardResizes = ResizeNone;
    NSLog(@"KeyboardPlugin: no resize");
  } else if ([resizeMode isEqualToString:@"ionic"]) {
    self.keyboardResizes = ResizeIonic;
    NSLog(@"KeyboardPlugin: resize mode - ionic");
  } else if ([resizeMode isEqualToString:@"body"]) {
    self.keyboardResizes = ResizeBody;
    NSLog(@"KeyboardPlugin: resize mode - body");
  }

  if (self.keyboardResizes == ResizeNative) {
    NSLog(@"KeyboardPlugin: resize mode - native");
  }

  self.hideFormAccessoryBar = YES;
  
  NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
  
  [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(onKeyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
  [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(onKeyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
  [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(onKeyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
  [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(onKeyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
  
  [nc removeObserver:self.webView name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
  [nc removeObserver:self.webView name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
  [nc removeObserver:self.webView name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
  [nc removeObserver:self.webView name:UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
}


#pragma mark Keyboard events

- (void)resetScrollView
{
  UIScrollView *scrollView = [self.webView scrollView];
  [scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}

- (void)onKeyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  [self setKeyboardHeight:0 delay:0.01];
  [self resetScrollView];
  hideTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 repeats:NO block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
    [self.bridge triggerWindowJSEventWithEventName:@"keyboardWillHide"];
    [self notifyListeners:@"keyboardWillHide" data:nil];
  }];
  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:hideTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

- (void)onKeyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  [self changeKeyboardStyle:self.keyboardStyle];
  if (hideTimer != nil) {
    [hideTimer invalidate];
  }
  CGRect rect = [[notification.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
  double height = rect.size.height;

  double duration = [[notification.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]+0.2;
  [self setKeyboardHeight:height delay:duration];
  [self resetScrollView];

  NSString * data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{ 'keyboardHeight': %d }", (int)height];
  [self.bridge triggerWindowJSEventWithEventName:@"keyboardWillShow" data:data];
  NSDictionary * kbData = @{@"keyboardHeight": [NSNumber numberWithDouble:height]};
  [self notifyListeners:@"keyboardWillShow" data:kbData];
}

- (void)onKeyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  CGRect rect = [[notification.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
  double height = rect.size.height;

  [self resetScrollView];

  NSString * data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{ 'keyboardHeight': %d }", (int)height];
  [self.bridge triggerWindowJSEventWithEventName:@"keyboardDidShow" data:data];
  NSDictionary * kbData = @{@"keyboardHeight": [NSNumber numberWithDouble:height]};
  [self notifyListeners:@"keyboardDidShow" data:kbData];
}

- (void)onKeyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  [self.bridge triggerWindowJSEventWithEventName:@"keyboardDidHide"];
  [self notifyListeners:@"keyboardDidHide" data:nil];
  [self resetScrollView];
}

- (void)setKeyboardHeight:(int)height delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
{
  if (self.paddingBottom == height) {
    return;
  }

  self.paddingBottom = height;

  __weak KeyboardPlugin* weakSelf = self;
  SEL action = @selector(_updateFrame);
  [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:weakSelf selector:action object:nil];
  if (delay == 0) {
    [self _updateFrame];
  } else {
    [weakSelf performSelector:action withObject:nil afterDelay:delay inModes:@[NSRunLoopCommonModes]];
  }
}

- (void)resizeElement:(NSString *)element withPaddingBottom:(int)paddingBottom withScreenHeight:(int)screenHeight
{
    int height = -1;
    if (paddingBottom > 0) {
        height = screenHeight - paddingBottom;
    }
    
    [self.bridge evalWithJs: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(function() { var el = %@; var height = %d; if (el) { el.style.height = height > -1 ? height + 'px' : null; } })()", element, height]];
}

- (void)_updateFrame
{
  CGRect f, wf = CGRectZero;
  UIWindow * window = nil;
    
  if ([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(window)]) {
    window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
  }
  
  if (!window) {
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
      UIScene *scene = [UIApplication sharedApplication].connectedScenes.allObjects.firstObject;
      window = [[(UIWindowScene*)scene windows] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isKeyWindow == YES"]].firstObject;
    }
  }
  if (window) {
    f = [window bounds];
  }
  if (self.webView != nil) {
    wf = self.webView.frame;
  }
  switch (self.keyboardResizes) {
    case ResizeBody:
    {
      [self resizeElement:@"document.body" withPaddingBottom:_paddingBottom withScreenHeight:(int)f.size.height];
      break;
    }
    case ResizeIonic:
    {
      [self resizeElement:@"document.querySelector('ion-app')" withPaddingBottom:_paddingBottom withScreenHeight:(int)f.size.height];
      break;
    }
    case ResizeNative:
    {
      [self.webView setFrame:CGRectMake(wf.origin.x, wf.origin.y, f.size.width - wf.origin.x, f.size.height - wf.origin.y - self.paddingBottom)];
      break;
    }
    default:
      break;
  }
  [self resetScrollView];
}


#pragma mark HideFormAccessoryBar

static IMP UIOriginalImp;
static IMP WKOriginalImp;

- (void)setHideFormAccessoryBar:(BOOL)hideFormAccessoryBar
{
  if (hideFormAccessoryBar == _hideFormAccessoryBar) {
    return;
  }
  Method UIMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(NSClassFromString(UIClassString), @selector(inputAccessoryView));
  Method WKMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(NSClassFromString(WKClassString), @selector(inputAccessoryView));
  if (hideFormAccessoryBar) {
    UIOriginalImp = method_getImplementation(UIMethod);
    WKOriginalImp = method_getImplementation(WKMethod);
    IMP newImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(^(id _s) {
      return nil;
    });
    method_setImplementation(UIMethod, newImp);
    method_setImplementation(WKMethod, newImp);
  } else {
    method_setImplementation(UIMethod, UIOriginalImp);
    method_setImplementation(WKMethod, WKOriginalImp);
  }
  _hideFormAccessoryBar = hideFormAccessoryBar;
}

#pragma mark scroll

- (void)setDisableScroll:(BOOL)disableScroll {
  if (disableScroll == _disableScroll) {
    return;
  }
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (disableScroll) {
      self.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
      self.webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
    }
    else {
      self.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
      self.webView.scrollView.delegate = nil;
    }
  });
  _disableScroll = disableScroll;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  [scrollView setContentOffset: CGPointZero];
}

#pragma mark Plugin interface

- (void)setAccessoryBarVisible:(CAPPluginCall *)call
{
  BOOL value = [call getBool:@"isVisible" defaultValue:FALSE];

  NSLog(@"Accessory bar visible change %d", value);
  self.hideFormAccessoryBar = !value;
  [call resolve];
}

- (void)hide:(CAPPluginCall *)call
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.webView endEditing:YES];
  });
  [call resolve];
}

- (void)show:(CAPPluginCall *)call
{
  [call unimplemented];
}

- (void)setStyle:(CAPPluginCall *)call
{
  self.keyboardStyle = [call getString:@"style" defaultValue:@"LIGHT"];
  [call resolve];
}

- (void)setResizeMode:(CAPPluginCall *)call
{
  NSString * mode = [call getString:@"mode" defaultValue:@"none"];
  if ([mode isEqualToString:@"ionic"]) {
    self.keyboardResizes = ResizeIonic;
  } else if ([mode isEqualToString:@"body"]) {
    self.keyboardResizes = ResizeBody;
  } else if ([mode isEqualToString:@"native"]) {
    self.keyboardResizes = ResizeNative;
  } else {
    self.keyboardResizes = ResizeNone;
  }
  [call resolve];
}

- (void)getResizeMode:(CAPPluginCall *)call
{
    NSString *mode;
    
    if (self.keyboardResizes == ResizeIonic) {
        mode = @"ionic";
    } else if(self.keyboardResizes == ResizeBody) {
        mode = @"body";
    } else if (self.keyboardResizes == ResizeNative) {
        mode = @"native";
    } else {
        mode = @"none";
    }
    
    NSDictionary *response = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:mode forKey:@"mode"];
    [call resolve: response];
}

- (void)setScroll:(CAPPluginCall *)call {
  self.disableScroll = [call getBool:@"isDisabled" defaultValue:FALSE];
  [call resolve];
}

- (void)changeKeyboardStyle:(NSString*)style
{
  IMP newImp = nil;
  if ([style isEqualToString:@"DARK"]) {
    newImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(^(id _s) {
      return UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
    });
  } else if ([style isEqualToString:@"LIGHT"]) {
    newImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(^(id _s) {
      return UIKeyboardAppearanceLight;
    });
  } else {
    newImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(^(id _s) {
      return UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault;
    });
  }
  for (NSString* classString in @[WKClassString, UITraitsClassString]) {
    Class c = NSClassFromString(classString);
    Method m = class_getInstanceMethod(c, @selector(keyboardAppearance));
    if (m != NULL) {
      method_setImplementation(m, newImp);
    } else {
      class_addMethod(c, @selector(keyboardAppearance), newImp, "l@:");
    }
  }
  _keyboardStyle = style;
}

#pragma mark dealloc

- (void)dealloc
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

@end
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, llevo tiempo intentando resolver inconvenientes anteriores pero con este error no he podido seguir

gracias

Comment: Estás usando el archivo con extensión `.xcworkspace`?

Comment: No, estoy usando el .xcodeproj

Comment: Deberías usar el archivo con extensión `.xcworkspace`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YA LO SOLUCIONE!!!

Simplemente me daba esos errores debido a que tenía mis librerías sin concordancia
es decir:

> @capacitor/core

Tenía una versión diferente a:

> @capacitor/app

Entonces por ello me daban esos errores que no son errores hehe